# Are justification questions off-topic?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, rules

I had a [template](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8526/90994) in the sandbox. that is a Justification of X in my world question.

So @JoinJBHonCodidact said me that my template was too story-based, I disagree in several ways but just one is important to note here. And it is that if my question is off-topic all the justification of why X in my world are all off-topic. This includes, but is no exclusive to

1. [Reason why the dystopian government would dress its policemen in civilian clothing?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/121119/reason-why-the-dystopian-government-would-dress-its-policemen-in-civilian-clothi)
2. [Is there any usage for a sea navy in a sci fi universe in which most planets are controlled by one government?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/216492/is-there-any-usage-for-a-sea-navy-in-a-sci-fi-universe-in-which-most-planets-are)

And in total are [132 more unpunisheed in anyway questions](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/search?q=Justification+is%3Aquestion+closed%3Ano+locked%3Ano+duplicate%3Ano+migrated%3Ano) in this site, about justification of X in my world.

So, are the justificationof X in my world questions off-topic (if no, then there is some problem with my template)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While there's nothing explicitly wrong with asking how to justify something, however a lot of questions asking for justification of x aren't a good fit for other reasons. It's similar to how questions asking "how to I program x?" are not well received on S.O They show no effort, and are generally very broad, ill defined, and are asking the answerers to do all the work. To quote from the help center if you're looking for discussion or brainstorming then this site probably isn't for you.

There are normally many justifications for a thing. This leads to questions with many valid answers which makes them too broad for this site.

Instead of asking for any justification for a thing. Ask yourself why you can't come up with a justification for X on your own. What unknowns are there that you don't have answers to that prevent you from justifying X? Ask us for help with solving that particular smaller problem instead. Such a question will be clearer, more specific and have fewer valid answers.